# Install PHP composer in existing docker image

Tags: docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I'm running [docker-letsencrypt](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt) through a `docker-compose.yml` file. It comes with PHP. I'm trying to run [PHP composer](https://getcomposer.org/) with it. I can install composer while being in the container through `bash`, but that won't stick when I recreate the container. How do I keep a permanent install of composer in an existing container that doesn't come with compose by default?

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:

  letsencrypt:
    image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
    container_name: letsencrypt
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - EMAIL=<mailadress>
      - URL=<tld>
      - SUBDOMAINS=<subdomains>
      - VALIDATION=http
      - TZ=Europe/Paris
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/letsencrypt:/config
```

I did find the one-line installer for composer:

```
php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
```

I could add this to `command` in my `docker-compose.yml`, but that would reinstall composer even on container restarts right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about your comment about the `command` option, it will indeed be run every time you launch your container.

One workaround would be to create your own dockerfile, as follow :

```
FROM linuxserver/letsencrypt
RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
```

(RUN directives are only run during the build step).

You should then modify your docker-compose.yml :

```
...
build: ./dir
  #dir/ is the folder where your Dockerfile resides
  #use the dockerfile directive if you use a non-default naming convention
  #or if your Dockerfile isn't at the root of your project 
container_name: letsencrypt
  ...
```